# Не получается запретить доступ не авторизованным пользователям на страницу

Tags: php, сессия

хочу запретить доступ не авторизованным пользователям на страницу index.php и если пользователь пишет в адресной строке **/index.php** его должно перекидать на **login.php**, то есть пользователю необходимо зарегистрироваться или залогиниться, дабы зайти на index.php.

В начале файла index.php, я написал код:

```
<?php include "init.php";?>
<?php if(!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])):?>
<?php  header("location:login.php");?>
<?php endif;?>
```

Если юзер не имеет user_id, то его должно перекидывать на index.php.

**init.php** Подключает классы, который относятся к базе данных.

```
<?php
session_start();
spl_autoload_register(function($class_name) {
   include "classes/$class_name.php";
});
?>
```

И когда я ввожу в адресной строке index.php, то меня перекидывает на index.php и отображаются эти ошибки:

Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at init.php on line 2

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at index.php on line 3

Менял кодировки файлов на utf-8.

Что не так делаю?Если есть какие-то подсказки или ошибки, то буду признателен, если скажите. Ибо уже пятый час сижу с этим и не понимаю.

Comment: Что то успевает вывести клиенту какие то символы. Это могут быть даже не видимые в редакторе символы вроде BOM (https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2). или например пустая строка в конце файла init или еще где нибудь. Посмотрите файлы в каком нибудь редакторе, позволяющем выводить в шестнадетиричном виде.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ! Сейчас открыл файлы index.php и init.php в редакторе Free Hex Editor и там действительно были слова перед открывающемся тегами <?php. до этого открывал в submile text, phpstorm, блокноте, microsoft visual studio и ничего не было. Спасибо ещё раз! А как можно избежать этого, когда появляются случайные символы в коде?

Comment: А в чем вы создавали изначально эти файлы ? Если я правильно понял это https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/save-as-utf8-without-bom/2984 то sublime text по умолчанию не пишет BOM. Ну и можно еще погуглить по запросу "sublime text BOM".

Comment: Я изначально использовал microsoft visual studio и там я создавал файлы, это потом уже начал искать в других текстовых редакторах ошибки в коде. Сейчас только что создал файл тестовый для проверки в чем сохраняет редактор и оказалось в Ascii, полазил в настройках редактора и поменял на utf8bom. Спасибо ещё раз за помощь.

Comment: @Mike Здравствуйте еще раз, а может ли быть такое, когда удаляешь файл с кодировкой ANSI(ошибся в прошлом комментарии) и создаешь заново его и задаешь кодировку UTF-8, выходит ошибка и файл автоматически меняется на ANSI и ошибка сама уходит, когда переходишь на другую страницу и обратно возвращаешься. Это баг у меня?Все работает, но почему utf-8 не хочет работать я не понимаю просто.

Comment: От редактора зависит. Некоторые редакторы опознают UTF8 именно по наличию BOM. Возможно их как то можно переучить, например где то задать что бы по умолчанию без BOM считала файл UTF. Но я обычно не использую редакторы под windows так что не знаю как там что